# Double countring the number of tracks

Tags: postgresql

An album Z has missing tracks if the Tracks table contains less rows for A than the number of tracks for A reported in the Albums table. For each album without missing tracks, find its total running seconds.

Comment: Upvote for the honest attempt to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an exercise, I don't want to spoil the learning effect totally by just giving you the final solution. I'll try to guide you there.

Your problem is the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE albums.tracks >= tracks.number
```

I guess you intend it to implement the requirement “for each album without missing tracks, …”.

However, that's not what the condition does; rather, it excludes tracks whose number exceeds the track count of the album.

You need something like: “where the count of tracks that are related to the album is (greater than or) equal to the album track count”.

In other words: `WHERE count(tracks.*) >= albums.tracks`. (The “related to the album” part is implemented by the join condition — it excludes tracks not related to the album.)

See? The secret is often just to translate a natural language sentence into SQL.

Now we are facing a problem, because we cannot have an aggregate function like `count` in the `WHERE` clause. This is because `WHERE` is processed *before* `GROUP BY` where the groups are formed.

Fortunately for us there is a kind of “`WHERE` clause” that is processed *after* grouping, and that is `HAVING`.

I leave the rest to you :^)

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the WHERE clause, but it still returned the same output  
`FROM albums join tracks on tracks.artist = albums.artist
WHERE albums.artist = tracks.artist 
GROUP BY albums.title, albums.artist
HAVING count(tracks.*) >= albums.tracks `

Comment: You can omit the `WHERE` clause now, as it is identical to the join condition. But you need to specify the *complete* foreign key in the join condition: `(tracks.artist, tracks.album_title) = (albums.artist, albums.title)`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I'm confused on what you mean by foreign key here. I did this and no bueno: SELECT distinct(albums.title), albums.artist, sum(tracks.length)
FROM albums join tracks on (tracks.artist, tracks.album) = (albums.artist, albums.title)
WHERE albums.artist = tracks.artist AND albums.title = tracks.title
GROUP BY albums.title, albums.artist
HAVING count(tracks.*) >= albums.tracks

Comment: Get rid of the unnecessary `DISTINCT` and `WHERE` condition, but that shouldn't change the result. Why don't you like the result? It seems to me that that is the correct solution.

Comment: Oh wait, yeah, getting rid of the DISTINCT and WHERE condition allowed an output, thanks!